# How can I repent for thinking of praying like my non-Muslim friends, which I later learned could be considered shirk?

Tags: shirk, tawba, forgiveness

When I was at age of 18-19, even though I could read the Quran at that time (Arabic), perform salah and fasted the full month on Ramadhan, I didn't know what "shirk" is, didn't heard of this word before age 21. At this age, I started gaining knowledge of this teaching of Islam, our beloved prophet and haram/halal all other stuff.

At this very age of 18-19, I thought of going to other place worship (i.e temple) and pray like my friends used to do, as all my friends are non-Muslim.
Now I realized that I thought of doing shirk. It is worst thing to do in one's life.

My question is: How can I repent, I have realized and asked with heart for forgiveness. Will I be forgiven?

Answer (score 1):

> Allah accepts **only the repentance of those who do evil in ignorance** and foolishness and repent soon afterwards; it is they to whom Allah will forgive and Allah is Ever All-Knower, All-Wise (Qur'an 4:17)

All I can say, you do your level best in getting closer with Allah, the rest.... leave it to Allah, and it's a suspense. But hope for good.

> O you who have believed, repent to Allah with sincere repentance. **Perhaps** your Lord will remove from you your misdeeds and admit you into gardens beneath which rivers flow [on] the Day when Allah will not disgrace the Prophet and those who believed with him. Their light will proceed before them and on their right; they will say, "Our Lord, perfect for us our light and forgive us. Indeed, You are over all things competent."

So, now to your final question...

> Will I be forgiven ?

After doing your level best efforts of asking forgiveness from Allah, then all we can say, is "We Don't Know", if Allah will accept our repentance or not, but all I can say is,

> ......And seek forgiveness of Allah. Verily, **Allah is Oft Forgiving**, Most Merciful. (Qur'an 73:20)

May the creator guide us all.

Comment: The last sentence of @servant-of-Wiser as he remarked "Allah is Oft Forgiving" can help you to be hopeful that Allah forgave you (if you really have done the steps of the repentance correctly).